# Redmine doesn't work properly in Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm trying to get Redmine (a Ruby on Rails app) working. It works fine when started with `ruby script/server webrick -e production`, however, I'm having trouble getting it working in Apache with Passenger.

Accessing http://example.com/redmine returns the Redmine home page, but clicking any link (or even adding a `/` to the URL) results in a 404. According to the Rails log, a `RoutingError` occurs. For example, when opening the projects page: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/projects.html" with {:method=>:get})`

The Redmine directory is `/var/www/localhost/htapps/redmine`. I followed the documentation at http://www.modrails.org/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application (section 3.2), so there's a symlink at `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/redmine` pointing to `../htapps/redmine/public`, and the Apache configuration contains `DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs` and `RailsBaseURI /redmine`.

What is causing it to raise these RoutingErrors?

Comment: Did you check your passenger configuration?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I followed the instructions at http://www.modrails.org/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application, specifically, section 3.2. It doesn't mention any Passenger configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue was actually caused by the default .htaccess included with Redmine.

Redmine's `.htaccess` rewrites every request to end with .html. Redmine's routes expect .html-less requests.

Setting `RewriteEngine` to `Off` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-fix-railsbaseuri-sub-uri-with.html

The manual workaround (according to what is suggested on the pages above) is adding the line below to config/environments/production.rb:

config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/redmine'

Comment: I think that that blog post describes a different issue. Their error message shows that the path includes 'myapp' (which would be 'redmine' in this case). My error message doesn't include that. In any case, I tried this workaround, but it results in a startup error: 'undefined method `relative_url_root=' for ActionController::Base:Class'

Answer (score 0):

If not deploying to a [Sub-URI](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI) **and** deploying using [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation.html), [adding](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/11264?r=11840#message-11840) the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]` to your `public/.htaccess` also solves the issue. As that rule is `IfModule`-ed out in the default `.htaccess`.

Another option is to [delete](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/11880?r=11938#message-11938) `.htaccess` if you're not using it (As an example you may be using it for additional layer authentication with `AuthType Digest` etc). It is [not required](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/FAQ#I-get-this-error-message-with-a-Passenger-deployment-ActionControllerRoutingError-No-route-matches-indexhtml-with-methodget) when deploying with passenger.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you will manage to run Redmine in suburi, redmine still will have issues.
Some pages won't be parsed and displayed correctly, if displayed at all.

This issue is almost one year old and indicated for next minor release. Btw dozen minor releases came out, but it's not yet fixed. [FCGI mode does not support sub-URI](http://www.redmine.org/issues/11881).